# retrieve auto_incremented ID of first INSERT for second INSERT

Tags: javascript, mysql, jdbc, google-apps-script

I'm using JDBC and google app script.
I need to insert rows created via an HTML interface, only problem is that rows contain 2 inputs that are represented in different tables of my MYSQL database.

My second table has a foreign key that references the first table (`product_id` references `id` from table `product`).

Here are my tables

**product:**

id, name

**product_quantity:**

id, product_id, quantity

Here is what I would like to achieve in pseudo-code:

```
function update(row){
  insertProductSQL = "INSERT INTO products (name) VALUES (" + row.name + ")";
  insertProductQuantity = "INSERT INTO products_quantity (product_id, quantity) VALUES (" + /*HERE IS THE PROBLEM*/ + ", " + row.quantity + ")"
  var conn = getConnection(); //JDBC connection object
  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  stmt.executeQuery(insertProductSQL)
  stmt = conn.createStatement();
  stmt.executeQuery(insertProductQuantity);
  conn.close();
}
```

So problem I'm facing is that I don't know if SQL or JDBC gives a simple way to retrieve the auto incremented value `id` created on the first `insert` to use it for my second `insert`.

Help is greatly appreciated, don't hesitate telling me if unclear to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function.

```
  insertProductQuantity = "INSERT INTO products_quantity (product_id, quantity) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), " + row.quantity + ")"
```

Comment: thanks a lot just found it before you answered but that confirms what I though. Best.